# How to display PBF tiles on MapLibre GL JS

Tags: javascript, vector-tiles, html, maplibre-gl, protobuf

I am new to MapLibre, I used to work a lot with Leaflet.
I am trying to display PBF vector tiles generated from QGIS, which I cannot display with Leaflet (I have errors trying to use [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid)). So I am trying to achieve this with MapLibre GL JS, but no luck so far: I don't have any error, but my tiles are not displayed. What do I do wrong ?

- **Note 1** : my pbf path is valid, I can access it from my browser
- **Note 2** : my inspiration is [[this example]](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js/docs/examples/vector-source/) from the MapLibre doc
- **Note 3** : *(edit)* My PBF tiles seems to load properly : if I write any invalid tile path, I get a 404 error, which seems legit. So my problem is that my tiles are not displayed.
- **Note 4** : *(edit)* My PBF tiles are loaded properly in QGIS using "Add Vector Tiles Layer", so it seems they are valid.

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>Vector tiles test</title>
  <!-- Maplibre GL -->
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@latest/dist/maplibre-gl.css" rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@latest/dist/maplibre-gl.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 750px;
      height: 750px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Vector tiles test</h1>
  <div id='map'></div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/script.js'></script>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
const accessToken = my_jawg_token
let map = new maplibregl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'https://api.jawg.io/styles/jawg-sunny.json?access-token='+accessToken,
  center: [6.1436, 45.9036],
  zoom: 13,
  minZoom: 10,
  maxZoom: 16
})

// MapLibre & PBF test
const pbf_path = 'http://localhost:8000/data/pbf_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
map.on('load', () => {
  map.addSource('local_pbf', {
    type: "vector",
    tiles: [pbf_path],
    minzoom: 0,
    maxzoom: 15
  })

  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'my_data',
    'type': 'line',
    'source': 'local_pbf',
    'source-layer': 'data',
    'layout': {
      'line-join': 'round',
      'line-cap': 'round'
    },
    'paint': {
      'line-color': '#ff69b4',
      'line-width': 1
    }
  })
})
```

Also, I struggle to find any good tutorial about MapLibre, I am interested I if you know any.

Comment: it looks correct. try adding promoteId: 'id' in the addSource. also double check that the source-layer is correct

Comment: Thanks for your reply. promoteId: 'id' did not change a thing. But maybe the problem is indeed with source-layer : I don't understand this attribute, neither from the example I used, nor from the doc : https://maplibre.org/maplibre-style-spec/layers/#source-layer. What should it refer to ?

Comment: bring one of the .pbf tiles into qgis and you should a sublayer name, use that name

Comment: Yes ! This is it ! I kinda understand the logic behind this, but I wish this would be explained somewhere, as one cannot understand pbf files as simplay as a json ... Thanks you very much !

Comment: I now have another issue though ... While some tiles are displayed correctly, at least one tile give an error :  `message: "Unable to parse the tile at http://localhost:8000/data/pbf_tiles/13/4235/2917.pbf, got error: undefined", stack: ""` This tile exists in my folder, but the only thing I see is that it is heavier than the others, 103Ko while other are from 1Ko to 21Ko

Comment: its hard to debug without seeing the tiles and the console, check if all the tiles are uncompressed. I've seen this error before but I don't remember how I fixed it

Comment: Indeed, I am starting to wonder if vector tiles output from QGIS are valid ... I also tried with a .mbtiles file generated from QGIS too, and I also have errors. I will investigate more about that. Thanks again for your replies